# Django Template firstof + filter

Tags: python, django, templates

I am using a Django template in my webapp, and am displaying values that are one of two things:

1. Numbers (up to 2 digits float)
2. The string "None"

What I'd like to do is:

1. Change "None" to 0, if value is "None".
2. Use Float Format to ensure value is displayed as 2nd digit float

Right now, I can do those separately:

```
{% firstof myValue 0.00 %}
```

(this outputs either the value or 0.00 if myValue = "None")

```
{{ myValue | floatformat:2 }}
```

(this formats the number to something like 2.70 for example, but doesn't change "None" to 0.00)

Is there a way to combine the functionality of those two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `if`

```
{% if myValue is None %}
  0.00
{% else %}
  {{ myValue | floatformat:2 }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and efficient way is to chain default_if and floatformat filters:

```
{{ myValue|default_if_none:0.00|floatformat:2 }}
```

1. When

   ```
   myValue = "22"
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   22.00
   ```
2. When

   ```
   myValue = None
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   0.00
   ```